# How so I access a variable XML element using XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file with variable tags (l0, l1 etc).

How do I refer to these tags in XSL?

I can loop on RuleXMLAsString with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="TPersistent_Promotion/RuleXMLAsString">
```

But can't access the 'data' tag within it as the l0, l1 etc. tag is variable.

Can I access each 'data' tag directly in XSL?

A search on wildcard on the tag for example?

```
<RuleXMLAsString Count="2">
  <l0><data>test1</data></l0>
  <l1><data>test2</data></l1>
</RuleXMLAsString>
```

Comment: You can access **elements** (not *tags*) whose names you don't know by using the `*` node test. Please show a [mcve] and the expected output, if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you the search on * worked!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is the path `*/data`.

If you want to be more specific and only match names of the form `l[0-9]`, then (a) you should ask whether this is a sensible XML design, and if the answer is yes, then (b) in XPath 2.0 you can use `*[matches(local-name(), 'l[0-9]')]/data`, or in XPath 1.0 `*[translate(local-name(), '0123456789', '0000000000') = 'l0']/data`.